# floated divs not aligning at top

Tags: html, css, alignment

I know there are a million questions about floating divs, but I haven't been able to find an answer that will help me solve my problem. I'm working on a website and there are two instances of floating divs that I would like to align across the top, but none of the million things I've tried thus far has worked.

The first instance is here: http://www.bluehighlandsbb.com/contact/. I would like the map that's on the right to be moved up so that it's aligned at the top with the name and address that are on the left.

The second instance is here: http://www.bluehighlandsbb.com. I would like the photos floating on the right to be moved up so that they are aligned on the top with the text that is currently above and to the left of the photos.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: 1) #contact-page-map has to come before the #address-form, and 2) #front-left-photo has to come before #home-text

Comment: Post some HTML and CSS.  As is, once the website is fixed, this question will be useless to anyone else.

Comment: Please add meaningful code and a problem description here. Don't just link 
to the site that needs fixing - otherwise, this question will lose any value
to future visitors once the problem is solved. Posting a 
[Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE)](http://www.sscce.org/) 
that demonstrates your problem would help you get better answers. For more info, 
see [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to
it?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Add `float: left;` on the `#address-form` div rather than the `#wpcf7-f7-p8-o1` div.